# Is it correct to protect questions with a lot of answers when a new user is posting a duplicate answer?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions, first-answers

When I'm in the first answer queue, it's quite common that a new user is posting an answer to a question with lots of answers that adds nothing to the existing answers. The short description for protecting is like this:

> Protect this question if it is highly active and likely to receive spam activity or non-answers (e.g. "Me too!" "Thanks!"). Anonymous and low reputation users can’t answer protected questions.

This is not really applicable. The answers I'm talking about are indeed proper answers. They are not spam, nor non-answers. They are just unnecessary.

The [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) says this:

> Protecting a question prevents answers from being added by anonymous and very low-reputation users, generally users with under 10 reputation.
>
> Questions should be protected when they are attracting poor answers from new users that exceed the volume which can be moderated in a timely manner.
>
> Questions should be unprotected when they are no longer attracting large amounts of traffic or would benefit from new answers.

This is a bit closer, because it addresses "poor answers". But here I'd say we have a slight problem, and that is that the short help text seems like it says something different than the long version. The short talks about "spam activity or non-answers" while the long version talks about "poor answers". I think that needs to be corrected.

And also, this is not about answers that are poor on their own. They are poor in relation to other answers in the sense that it adds nothing.

I'm not talking about a specific question here, but just as an example we have [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13137817/6699433) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70752649/6699433) I was reviewing was this:

> you can binary write content of the response:
>
> ```
> import requests
> resp = requests.get('https://url.to.png')
> with open('file.png','wb') as f:
>    f.write(resp.content)
> ```

And the content here can already be found in several other answers.

In this particular example, the question is already protected, but if it wasn't would it be correct to protect it? The action I took this time was downvoting and commenting that it adds nothing to existing answers.

Comment: I would say it is correct to protect them, if there are many answers or they seem to cover question well. In other words, when you don't expect that new answers will be able to contribute much. Of course, as technology changes there might be a need for additional answers, but in such cases there will be plenty of users with rep above 10 to add them. New users are much more likely to add repeating or nonsense answers on such high profile questions and this is exactly what this feature is about.

Comment: While I agree with Dalija's comment, I have to note that in its current state the protection feature is mostly a joke - while it *does* help protect high-profile Q&As from literally first-time posters, it does little to nothing to stop users that have at least one question (or, worse, any post if we go out of the FA queue context) with *one* upvote under their belt...

Comment: @OlegValter I whole heartily agree. 10 reputation is pretty low bar and I have seen many questions where it would have to be much higher to prevent abuse.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I agree here. 10 rep is a VERY low bar. It's so low that the sentence *"Questions should be unprotected when they are no longer attracting large amounts of traffic"* could be completely removed. Maybe it could be a good idea to automatically prevent users with rep lower than 50 to answer questions with more than 5 answers. (The numbers can be discussed)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar yeah, the bar is *extremely* low to the point of being effectively useless as a prevention measure. If it was up to me, protecting questions would prevent *any* user with 0 answers under their belt from posting one (as I highly doubt there is a significant number of users who can just drop by a prominent Q&A and post something non-redundant). Another alternative is to require at least 101 rep (based on the association bonus). Too bad nothing that we discuss here will happen in the foreseeable future...

Comment: It's unfortunate that the level of attention applied to the "out of date answers" problem isn't applied to that of low-quality answers accruing to popular Q&As.  Some of these answers may be removed as dupes of existing, but many are so user-specific that they can't justifiably be removed.  One can argue that they are harmless because they will never rise out of the third page of answers, but they cost reviewer time, and they obscure late good answers, as few visitors will wade through all the poor answers to see them.

Comment: @OlegValter The association bonus is not considered for the 10 rep you need on protected questions. The banner should mention this (e.g. "earn 10 reputation **on this site**")... Having 1 rep + 100 from assoc bonus, in other words, won't let you answer protected questions.

Comment: It would be great if they split the 'protect' option into two different ones... you click "protect" and you are presented with a dropdown w/ two options: first option is "protect from spam" and sets the normal '10 rep on this site' requirement and auto-expires after two weeks. Second option could be "protect from low quality answers" and sets a '100 rep on this site' requirement and never expires.

Comment: @TylerH yeah, I mean basing the increase on the current association bonus, but making it a hard requirement - at least 101 rep on the site. I like the idea of the split protection types - some questions do not need to be harshly protected indeed. Maybe something along the lenes of the bounty system could work here

Comment: I asked for a change to this feature recently, due to junk answers on the branch predictor question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371700/can-we-raise-the-threshold-for-protected-questions.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, it is entirely appropriate to protect canonical and/or high traffic posts that tend to attract a lot of such answers. New users cluttering down canonical posts with low-quality answers is a big quality problem of this site.

Also make sure to:

- Down-vote such answers if they don't add anything that's already been said. Particularly if they just post a fragment of what's already been said in an already present higher quality answer.
- Always look out for plagiarism, it's surprisingly common that someone just copy paste parts of an existing answer and post it as their own.

Comment: For answers which are fully duplicated in existing answers (but are not obviously plagiarism), do not offer an alternative presentation, nor add new insight, consider also casting a delete vote.

Comment: I have a boiler-plate comment that I add to new answers of the type under discussion: _Welcome to Stack Overflow.
If you decide to answer an older question that has well established and
correct answers, adding a new answer late in the day may not get you any
credit.
If you have some distinctive new information, or you're convinced the
other answers are all wrong, by all means add a new answer, but 'yet
another answer' giving the same basic information a long time after the
question was asked usually won't earn you much credit._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler nice text, mind if I "plagiarize" you? :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nice one. But I'd prefer something that explicitly says that not only is it unlikely to result in any credit, but also unwanted noise that may attract downvotes.

Comment: @Cristik — it is there for use by anyone who would like to use it.. I won't regard it as plagiarism, and attempting to give credit would be silly.

Comment: @klutt — Yes, it does not point out the downvote possibilities, but depressingly frequently the answer accumulates or has accumulated a couple of upvotes, so the apparent result doesn't match a more negative commentary.  YMMV — adapt to suit yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I most often see it in the first answer queue. There it's very uncommon with up votes, but that's quite natural. :)

Comment: @klutt – I seem to come across these answers most often when I'm looking at updated favourites, typically some days after the answer was added.  I don't spend much time in the 'first answer' review queue.  For a question that gets this comment from me, see [What is the difference between `git pull` and `git fetch`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: Re: _"New users cluttering down canonical posts with low-quality answers is a big quality problem of this site."_ - I've suggested accordions before. I'm not sure why SO doesn't use accordions. I concede there may be a good reason why not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I came looking for this comment after the bounty on SO's highest-voted question (about branch prediction) attracted three new [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70795222) today from low rep users, two of them from the same user (the first of which was answering to a different question, which is a common mis-step for new answers on that).  I really wish there was a way to raise the bar for answers to that question; I've regularly had to point out / correct misinformation in new answers, and some edits to Mysticial's answer. (Occasionally resulting in a decent new answer).